# creating pop out menu

Tags: css, menu, navigation, menubar

I would like to create a pop out menu. Clicking menu bar opens a navigation page over the home page. However, I could not see the close button in the navigation page. May be it is a issue with z-index, but I am really stuck with this problem. Please look at the code in

```
<header class="header cd-header">
<div  class="logo left">
    <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png">
        <img src="images/logo_white.png" style="display:none;opacity:1;">
</div>
    </header>
    <nav class="cd-primary-nav small-1 column">
        <div class="white_logo ">
            <img src="images/logo_white.png">
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Work</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Capabilities</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Culture</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Bable Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a class="cd-primary-nav-trigger" href="#0">
            <div class=" active cd-header">
                <div class="nav menu right">
                    <span class=" icon-container">
                        <span class="line line01"></span>
                        <span class="line line02"></span>
                        <span class="line line03"></span>
                        <span class="line line04"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shumana/j0dLt24p/5/
and help me out. Here, cd-primary-nav contains the close button. Evenif I have put high z-index to that class, it does not work.

Thank you in advance!